# how to override the delete button in one2many from sale order

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, unlink, one2many

in one2many line delete button is there when a boolean field is true in that line the line will not delete and raise an exception. i do like the below code

but i will not effected in code. there is no any response the line deleted. please.... tell me any one

thanks in advance....

```
from odoo import api, models, fields, _, SUPERUSER_ID
import string
from odoo import exceptions
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError


class ouc_sale_order(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    c_state = fields.Selection(
        [("draft", "Draft Proforma Invoice"), ("sent", "Proforma Invoice Sent"), ("cancel", "Cancelled"),
         ("waiting_date", "Waiting Schedule"), ("progress", "Sales Order"), ("manual", "Sale to Invoice"),
         ("shipping_except", "Shipping Exception"), ("invoice_except", "Invoice Exception"), ("done", "Done")],
        string='State')


class ouc_sales_order_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    c_status = fields.Selection([('New', 'New'), ('renewal', 'Renewal'), ('upgrade', 'Upgrade'), ('upsell', 'Upsell'), ('PDC', 'PDC'),
         ('etc', 'etc')], string='Status', default='New')
    c_fptags_id = fields.Many2one('ouc.fptag', string='FPTAGs')
    c_product_template_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string='Product Template', related='product_id.product_tmpl_id')
    c_package_id = fields.Many2one('ouc.package', string='Packages')
    c_pkg_expiry_in_month = fields.Integer(string='Package Expires After(Months)', related='c_package_id.validity')
    c_subtotaltax = fields.Float('Subtotal with Tax')
    c_taxamount = fields.Float('Tax Amount')
    c_client_id = fields.Char('Client Id')
    c_default_discount = fields.Float('Default Discount (%)')
    c_max_discount = fields.Float('Maximum Discount (%)')
    c_subscription_status = fields.Boolean(string='Subscription')


#@api.multi
#def unlink(self):
#    for record in self:
#        if record.c_subscription_status:
#            raise exceptions.ValidationError(_('You didn\'t delete this record'))
#    return super(ouc_sales_order_line,self).unlink()
```

Comment: Can you please specify the model structure here?

Comment: Your code seems proper there is no any issue. Can you please show us where you have added this method in model ?

Comment: i have added in the comodel of the parent class. the comodel is sale.order.line

Comment: one2many in sale.order---->main class

Comment: one2many fields in ---->sale.order.line    please check it once it is not effected.

Comment: Please share the complete code structure, might be issue somewhere else.

Comment: from odoo import api, models, fields, _, SUPERUSER_ID
class ouc_sale_order(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order' 
class ouc_sales_order_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'
    c_subscription_status = fields.Boolean(string='Subscription')
    @api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.c_subscription_status:
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(_('You didn\'t delete this record'))  
            return super(ouc_sales_order_line,self).unlink()

Comment: sorry for the late reply.....

Comment: You can edit your question and specify the code update over there. Writing code in comment is not recongnizable.

Comment: i sended  the code please check once

Comment: You commented the 'unlink' code, please try to add it wherever you have applied it. It will give the better idea to identify the problem.

Comment: i just using boolean field only.

Comment: please check it ur module in one2many when boolean field is true the record is not delete and raise an exception... please do it once.....

Comment: Just try to put the 'unlink' code to appropriate model un-comment it, so that we can get to know, where have you applied that code. Try to put exact code whatever you have tried.

Comment: sorry yaa iam not understand. please once try ur module any one2many

Answer (score 1):

This code of your is working!!!

Just done little correction > Added default=False in field.(not necessary but good practice!)

```
class ouc_sales_order_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    c_subscription_status = fields.Boolean(string='Subscription', default=False)

    @api.multi
    def unlink(self):
       for record in self:
           if record.c_subscription_status:
               raise ValidationError(_('You didn\'t delete this record'))
       return super(ouc_sales_order_line, self).unlink()
```

> Get order in which your boolean field is set TRUE in order_line delete record and > save > it will raise validation error you placed!